# Combinaions from X,Y string in massive

Tags: delphi

Firs of all excuse me for my bad english.
I'm trying to generate combinations of symbols taking them from str: TStringList (Xn, Yn) where X is the position of the char in the new word and Y is the variable for the position.
 For example lets say my StringList have

```
str[0]: '013456789'          
str[1]: 'abcdef'
str[2]: '5421'
```

In this case I will expact 216 words (length(str[0]) * length(str[1]) * length(str[2])) The result will be like:

```
str[0][1]+ str[1][1]+ str[2][1] -> 0a5
str[0][1]+ str[1][1]+ str[2][2] -> 0a4
str[0][1]+ str[1][1]+ str[2][3] -> 0a2
str[0][1]+ str[1][1]+ str[2][4] -> 0a1

str[0][1]+ str[1][2]+ str[2][1] -> 0b5
str[0][1]+ str[1][2]+ str[2][2] -> 0b4
str[0][1]+ str[1][2]+ str[2][3] -> 0b2
str[0][1]+ str[1][2]+ str[2][4] -> 0b1

str[0][1]+ str[1][3]+ str[2][1] -> 0c5
str[0][1]+ str[1][3]+ str[2][2] -> 0c4
str[0][1]+ str[1][3]+ str[2][3] -> 0c2
str[0][1]+ str[1][3]+ str[2][4] -> 0c1
```

and so on untill

```
str[0][10]+ str[1][6]+ str[2][3] -> 9f2 
str[0][10]+ str[1][6]+ str[2][4] -> 9f1
```

Now I'm comfused how to make the "FOR" loops to make cicles for every possible word.

Best regards Martin

Comment: Will you know the word count in your `str` string list in advance (at compilation time) ?

Comment: No, the str count and the length of each str are loaded in runtime.

Comment: Sounds like homework? :)

Comment: :D No is not, Just a project for fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with recursion.

```
procedure Recurse(startIx,stopIx: Integer; prefix: String; const aList: TStringList);
var
  ch : Char;
begin
  if (startIx > stopIx) then begin
    WriteLn(prefix);
  end
  else
  begin
    for ch in aList[startIx] do begin
      Recurse( startIx+1,stopIx,prefix + ch,aList);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

```
Recurse(0,str.Count-1,'',str);
```

Recursion may seem like magic at first, but is a very effective way to solve this kind of combinatorics.

The solution to this problem is a [`Cartesian product`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Should you have an older Delphi version, iterate the character like this:

```
procedure Recurse(startIx,stopIx: Integer; prefix: String; const aList: TStringList);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  if (startIx > stopIx) then begin
    WriteLn(prefix);
  end
  else
  begin
    for i := 1 to Length(aList[startIx]) do begin
      Recurse( startIx+1,stopIx,prefix + aList[startIx][i],aList);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: hm I don know why but I can't use "for ch in aList[startIx]" becose of error "Operator not applicatible to this operend type". Maybe old version of Delphi? (curently with 7)

Comment: Yes is working good thanks. Now I will test the two methods with 1m combinations to see the difference in the speed of the "generation".

Comment: Then you might add the printout into a stringlist instead of writing it to the console. Have fun :-)

Comment: So your method is more than 2 times faster then the method of nio. 10x  to both of you and best regards!

Answer (score 1):

You have to nest 3 for loops together. I assume that index of str array starts from zero but indices of second dimension start from 1:

```
var i,j,k:integer;

begin
    s = '';
    for i:=1 to length(str[0]) do
        for j:=1 to length(str[1]) do
            for k:=1 to length(str[2]) do
            begin
                combination := str[0][i]+str[1][j]+str[2][k];
                s := s + combination + chr(13) + chr(10);
            end;
    { you have all combinations in string s }
end;
```

If you need variable number of character length you could implement it like this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var str: array [0..10] of string;
    lengths : array [0..10] of integer;
    combination : string;
    index: array [0..10] of integer;
    n, i,j : integer;
    maxn : integer;
begin
    n := 3; { actual number of charaters in output word }
    str[0]:= '013456789';
    str[1]:= 'abcdef';
    str[2]:= '5421';


    { lengths will be used often later so they will be determined one time }
    for i:=0 to n-1 do lengths[i] := length(str[i]);
    maxn := 1; { maxn will be used to determine how meny iterations to make }
    for i:=0 to n-1 do maxn := maxn * lengths[i];
    { start at index 1 (first character) with each character position }
    for i:=0 to n-1 do index[i]:=1;


    memo1.Lines.Add(inttostr(maxn));

    { iterate all possibilities }
    for i:=1 to maxn do
    begin
      { start creating a combination }
      combination:='';
      for j:=0 to n-1 do
      begin
        combination := combination + str[j][index[j]];
      end;
      memo1.Lines.Add(combination);
      { increment indexes, from last to the first }
      for j:=n-1 downto 0 do
      begin
        index[j] := index[j]+1;
        { if index is in bounds of character posibilities stop incremented indexes,
          otherwise reset the index and increment next one }
        if index[j]<=lengths[j] then
        begin
            break; { stop incrementing indexes }
        end else begin
            index[j] := 1; { reset the index }
            { the loop will continue incrementing previous index }
        end;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

Instead of using fixed variables for character index like `i,j,k` you can store them in an array `index`. Incrementing of indexes works like when you hand add two numbers on a paper. Try to add

```
 999
+  1
----
```

to get the idea.

Comment: What if the number of strings is n?

Comment: My last script is just like yours. But now I am limited to loops count. So my questions is how to do FOR loops in runtime according to 'str.Count-1' For example with different conditions I will have str.count 100 (100 characters for every generated word). And sorry for my explonation in my first post.

Comment: you can store indexes in an array instead of fixed variables like i,j,k you can then solve the problem with maximum of two nested for cycles

Comment: This works more than well. Now I will look into. Thank you for the fastest replay. I will add repotation later becose my is too small now!